# How do I automatically sync a file from a local Mac to Mac OS X Server?

Tags: macos, automation

I have a Mac running Mac OS X Server and there are three other Macs connected to the local network.

All our data is stored on the server and the server backs up every day to an external hard drive using Time Machine.

I want to synchronize certain files from our three local machines to the server once a day.

**Is there a simple way to do automate this process?**

Comment: rsync: [read this article](http://www.egg-tech.com/mac_backup/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend using **Automator** and `rsync` to accomplish this:

First, you'll want to make sure that the share you want the three client machines to sync to is mounted on each client computer, so the following command knows where to go to put the data.

1. Open Automator from `/Applications`
2. Create a new **iCal Alarm** workflow
3. Find the "**Run Shell Script**" Automator action
4. type in the text box: "`rsync -ax /path to file you want to sync from  /path to file you want to sync to`" In the case of syncing from a Mac to a server on the network, the path will look like this: `/Volumes/Share/Path`
5. Click the **Run** button in Automator to test this action (you may want to test the command out in Terminal with some dummy files first).
6. If the workflow is working properly, you can save it. When you save and name it, it should open iCal on your client computer and place the new iCal Alarm you just created in the calendar. You can then change the date and time that this should run, as well as set it to **repeat** on certain days of the week.
7. From here, you can either duplicate these steps on the other client machines or share the event via email.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

[ChronoSync](http://econtechnologies.com/pages/cs/chrono_overview.html), [File Replication Pro,](http://www.filereplicationpro.com/) and [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) would all accomplish this. You could create a Dropbox account for the server and each user could share a folder with the server's Dropbox account.

Other approaches are to use [CrashPlan](http://www.crashplan.com/) to backup from the clients to the server, or backup the clients to the server with Time Machine.